# Можно ли заменить "or" и "and" для сокращения кода в Lua?

Tags: lua

Можно ли заменить "or" и "and" для сокращения кода в Lua? Например можно ли сократить следующие коды:

```
if arm == 11 or arm == 12 or arm == 14 or arm == 17 or arm == 18 or arm == 29 then
```

--или еще пример

```
if arm > 11 and arm < 19 then
```

--или

```
if arm > 11 and arm < 15 or arm > 20 and
  arm < 27 or arm > 38 and arm < 50 then
```

Comment: LUA плохо знаю. Может нужен `switch` для первого варианта. Либо использовать таблицу переходов. Но последний вариант будет гораздо хуже в выразительности.

Comment: на что заменить? если хотите что-то типа `between` или `in`, то такого нет в Lua, и если бы даже было - короче не будет.

Comment: Хотелось бы заменить на какое-то перечисление, чтоб не писать 15 раз "or" или "and"

Comment: например на такое if arm ==11,15,20 и т.д. или if arm ==11 or 15 or 20 и т. д.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33510736/5045688